# wordpress custom login form for custom database

Tags: wordpress

i have used

```
    gloabal $wpdb;
```

to create custom table for users in the database
can wordpress support login to be retrieved from this database with it's security?

so i can make in the home page a place for username and password ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your custom users table has a matching userid in WordPress...it can work.  Have your custom code authenticate the user using your own table, match the custom user to a wordpress user id, then use the wordpress functions to login a wordpress userid.

Comment: how can i match the user_id of wordpress with my users table ?

Comment: you need to define a way to match, and ensure that both tables have a way of being joined. Since data models can vary, you will have to look at it your self. 2 possible options: match based on username or email....or add the wordpress userid to your users table.

Comment: thanks alot Adam i did the second option and i added the wp_users ID to my table but i have a problem that when i insert wrong password it take me to www.mydomin.com/wp-admin.php to re-enter the password, do u have any way to make it look like this: http://rocketgeek.com/

Comment: Does your custom user's table password match the wordpress user's table password? Odds are no...so you'll have to look into alternative ways of logging in a user into wordpress. There are a few. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_current_user